# how to use JTA in jboss spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jboss7.x

i am using the JTA with hibernate by this i am having an Ear file which have the multiple war file when i am deploy the Ear file in glassfish it runs fine but when i am running that Ear file in Jboss it give s me the some error

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [persistenceContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: EW] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
16:54:55,678 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-8)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1486)
16:54:55,678 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-8)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
16:54:55,679 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-8)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
16:54:55,680 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-8)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
16:54:55,680 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-8)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
16:54:55,681 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-8)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
16:54:55,682 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-8)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
16:54:55,682 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-8)    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1117)
16:54:55,683 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-8)    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:922)
16:54:55,683 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-8)    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
16:54:55,684 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-8)    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
16:54:55,685 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-8)    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
16:54:55,685 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-8)    at com.eyewatch.dao.util.DAOLocator.<clinit>(DAOLocator.java:15)
```

Comment: Please post your `persistence.xml` that should help us to help you!

Comment: The class that throws this excpetion frightens me.. `DAOLocator`... Looks like dependency lookups all over the place, I hope that there is n't ServiceLocator which also constructs an `ApplicationContext`. Alas, please post the full stacktrace I expect there is more (somewhere) and please add the spring configuration and persistence.xml

Answer (score 0):

To use JBOSS JTA you shouldn't configure anything on the matter in the `persistence.xml`, except that `<jta-data-source>`

To use JBOSS JTA from Spring application it's just enough to add this to config:

```
<tx:jta-transaction-manager/>
```

Note, it's better to allow to raise the Persistence Unit to JBOSS: place your `persistence.xml` to the `META-INF` of your jar.
And get the `entityManagerFactory` from JNDI:

`persistence.xml`:

```
<property name="jboss.entity.manager.factory.jndi.name" value="persistence/MY-UNIT"/>
```

`application.xml`

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="emf" jndi-name="persistence/MY-UNIT"/>

<bean id="entityManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.SharedEntityManagerBean"
          p:entityManagerFactory-ref="emf"/>
```

Having that you can continue to use `@PersistenceContext` in your services

Comment: in my standalone.xml <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/jdbc/test-standalone" pool-name="ewschema" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ewschema</connection-url>
                    <driver>mySql</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>root</user-name>
                        <password>root</password>
                    </security>
                </datasource>

Comment: after doing many effort i am getting this error or msg  ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("data-source" => "java:/jdbc/test-standalone")
]) - failure description: {"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
    "jboss.driver-demander.java:/jdbc/test-standalone is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql]",
    "jboss.data-source.java:/jdbc/test-standalone is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql]"
]}